# Как сделать функцию генерации кнопок Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Мне надо создать 120 кнопок, и писать их в вручную не имею желания, да и в дальнейшем точно будет подобные ситуации. Поэтому и хочу создать функцию для создания кнопок

```
def creat_button(a):
    count_1 = 1
    count_0 = 0
    count_2 = 2
    try:
        markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        for i in a:
            markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(a[count_0], callback_data='1'),  InlineKeyboardButton(a[count_1], callback_data='2'),
                   InlineKeyboardButton(a[count_2], callback_data='3'))
            count_0 += 3
            count_1 += 3
            count_2 += 3
    except IndexError:
        print(count_0)
    finally:
        return markup
```

Это пока единственное до чего я смог додуматься, если будут какие-то замечания к коду или у вас будет уже созданная  подобная функция, буду рад выслушать или посмотреть

Comment: Можете не сомневаться, ведь у меня получилось

Comment: прими чей-либо ответ, или напиши свой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вот так.

```
def gen_markup(quanity: int, prefix: str, row_width: int) -> InlineKeyboardMarkup:
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=row_width)
    for i in range(quanity):
        markup.insert(InlineKeyboardButton(f"text {i}", callback_data=f"{prefix}:{i}"))
    return markup


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def bot_message(message: types.Message):
    markup = gen_markup(30, "prefix", 5)
    await message.answer("asd", reply_markup=markup)
```

Результат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это при условии что вы подаете список строк для названия кнопок.

```
def gen_markup(texts: list, prefix: str, row_width: int) -> InlineKeyboardMarkup:
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=row_width)
    for num, text in enumerate(texts):
        markup.insert(InlineKeyboardButton(f"{text}", callback_data=f"{prefix}:{num}"))
    return markup
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Уже использую эту функцию в коде

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так:

```
def gen(lst, n):
    count=0
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        count+=1
        yield [{'text':i, 'callback_data':num+n*(count-1)} \
            for num, i in enumerate(lst[i:i + n])]

keyboard={
    'inline_keyboard': list(gen(a, 3)) #тут задаем кол-во столбцов
}
```

Этот код рассчитан на инпут формата `[1,2,3,4,...]` или `['слово1','слово2',...]`
Он сгенерирует клавиатуру такого вида:

'Кнопка 1', callback='1' |  'Кнопка 2', callback='2' | 'Кнопка 3', callback='3'